# What does "Senders" and "Recipients" mean in this context?

Tags: terminology, sending, receiving, blockchain-explorer

https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/address/3GauXQPcAgntyhxFdz9jiEf1VTiZYbNdh7

For each transaction, it mentions, for example:

> Senders: 80
>
> Recipients: 1

What exactly does this mean?

(Also, that's one very rich dude who sent 0.25 BTC as a donation to this live streamer...)

Comment: Incorrect terms used by block explorer IMO. It should just be inputs and outputs for all bitcoin transactions.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, "senders" and "receivers" are just different terms for transaction inputs and outputs. This terminology is somewhat misleading, because while the inputs can belong to different people/entities, more often than not they all belong to the same entity (this has led to the so-called "common input ownership heuristic").